# dalelotts angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker display 24h format in timepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Dalelotts Datetimepicker.

[DateTimePicker](https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

I was wondering if there is a way to set so that the dateTIMEpicker shows 24h in the timepicker than AM/PM time..

[image: The current display of time in my datetimepicker]

IE: 09:00 & 21:00 instead of 9:00AM & 9:00PM

Here is the code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.templates.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/css/datetimepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">



<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6">
  <lable class="lfInputLable">From date</lable>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="data.dateDropDownInput1" data-date-time-input="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.dateDropDownInput1" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown1' }" />
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set a local with moment.js or create one with custom formats, https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker#hour-and-minute-formats

Comment: Could you please give me some kind of example or pointer to the right direction, i'm not sure i understand your comment fully. Thank you for answering btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is determined by moment.js - See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

You can set the `LT`, `ll` and `lll` formats to the format you want displayed in the date/time picker. See https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker#hour-and-minute-formats

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested by dale.lotts works.
Just check that your moment.js is loaded with your desired locale, you can check it with:  `console.log(moment.locales)`.
If it's loaded with just the "en" locale you need to include the `moment-with-locales.js` in your project.

Then in your code you can simply set your locale with, for example: 
`moment.locale("de-ch");` 
and the time will be shown in 24h format

[DateTimePicker with other locale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJDe3.png)

Answer (score -1):

Found it!

in the datetimepicker.js file inside the hourModelFactory function i had to change:

```
'display': hourMoment.format('LT'),
```

to:

```
'display': hourMoment.format('HH:mm'),
```

the other thing now is that the previousViewDate button that shows the chosen time and also acts as a button to go back in the picker -  still shows AM/PM time..

[image: DateTimePicker]

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There is no need to change the code in the picker. Review the documentation for moment and note that you can create a custom format and define the `LT` and `ll` formats to be whatever format you need.  See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/  - and https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker#hour-and-minute-formats

Comment: Thanks Dale! i was actually fiddling around d trying to find another way, and just as you said i created costume format to define the properties i wanted. Worked like a charm! Thank you for the wonderful software!

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad you like it!

Answer (score -1):

```
function minuteModelFactory (milliseconds) {
    var selectedDate = moment.utc(milliseconds).startOf('hour')
    var previousViewDate = moment.utc(selectedDate).startOf('day')

    var minuteFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm'
    var activeFormat = formatValue(ngModelController.$modelValue, minuteFormat)
    var currentFormat = moment().format(minuteFormat)

    var result = {
      'previousView': 'hour',
      'currentView': 'minute',
      'nextView': 'setTime',
      'previousViewDate': new DateObject({
        utcDateValue: previousViewDate.valueOf(),
        display: selectedDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY H:mm')
      }),
      'leftDate': new DateObject({utcDateValue: moment.utc(selectedDate).subtract(1, 'hours').valueOf()}),
      'rightDate': new DateObject({utcDateValue: moment.utc(selectedDate).add(1, 'hours').valueOf()}),
      'dates': []
    }

    var limit = 60 / configuration.minuteStep

    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i += 1) {
      var hourMoment = moment.utc(selectedDate).add(i * configuration.minuteStep, 'minute')
      var dateValue = {
        'active': hourMoment.format(minuteFormat) === activeFormat,
        'current': hourMoment.format(minuteFormat) === currentFormat,
        'display': hourMoment.format('HH:mm'),
        'utcDateValue': hourMoment.valueOf()
      }

      result.dates.push(new DateObject(dateValue))
    }

    return result
  }
```

display: selectedDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY H:mm')